# proper use of mkdir()

Tags: php, mkdir, laravel

I have a directory path '/uploads/files'. When a user registers, I'm trying to append their user_id to the end of the path to make it 'uploads/files/user_id' so that each user has their own upload folder to upload to. I'm using Laravel, and my current code looks like this...

```
mkdir("uploads/files/" . Auth::user()->id);
```

Is this the proper way to create a new folder? I've been playing around with it a bunch of different ways and can't seem to get anything to work.

Comment: What is happening when you are trying above mentioned code? If you are getting some type of error, can you please mention it here.

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object error, same line as the code.

Comment: try to echo Auth::user()->id first, the type of error you have mentioned, i guess the problem is in it. Its just a suggestion though.

Comment: try `var_dump(Auth::user());exit;` that should give you some ideas... maybe it returns `array` or `null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mkdir` is the way to go. However you need to keep in mind that linux permission must be set correctly for this to work. Make sure you have writing rights. You can check with `is_writable($dirPath)`. Set the permission to `755` or whatever you think works best for your application.

You can also use linux syntax like below... it's handy for more complex operations.

```
 $path = '/uploads/files/user_id_dir';
 shell_exec("mkdir -p $path");
```

Comment: couldn't seem to get the linux syntax to work, but what did work was $path = 'uploads/files/' . Auth::user()->id;
mkdir($path, 0700);

Answer (score 1):

if you dont want your directories to be easily accessible and guessable, you can just do a hash of your user_id and then append to it. this is just fine as a plain simple case. But from the security point, this might be a threat.

just use `md5()` or `sha1()` along with a random complex string as a `salt` to keep your directories secured and far from being guessed.

and one other thing is put this inside an if condition to check if the folder is already created.

```
$path = 'path_to_your_directory';
if(!file_exists($path)
{
     //then create the directory
}
else
{
    //do the upload here
}
```

EDIT :  if you are using `Auth::user()->id`, the user must be logged in to the site. i.e. a session must exist. Else it wont work. Guess you know that.

Comment: Still able to list dir and hack the matches.

Comment: @coryjacik, don't hash it. Better secure your Server.

Comment: you can always use htaccess or a simple blank index.html to stop listing the directory. in .htaccess it will be as simple as `Options  -Indexes` isn't it?

Comment: .htaccess is not preferred way as it's run-time and who said his uploads are under document root?

Comment: well he didnt say that..but just for a little security i added that info in case he is just plain simple uploading things. can you explain the part "Better secure your server"?

Comment: 1. Don't place uploads directory under doc root. 2. Use software like AppArmor and others. 3. Harden your servers...

Comment: Thanks guys, this is all local still..haven't even started to think about security yet but you bring up some good points. Laravel seems like it has some pretty solid security built into it out of the box